# Problem with updating a QProgressDialog with QCoreApplication:processEvents in a constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I have two classes, one class is named A, and second one is named B.

B class has a constructor which is doing this stuff:

```
void B::B(const QString &filepath) {
    QImageReader reader = QImageReader(filepath);
    int numImages = 0;

    QProgressDialog dialog("Loading images..", "Abort", 0, reader.imageCount());

    while (true) {
        QImage image = reader.read();
        if (image.isNull()) {
            break;
        }
        imagevec.push_back(image);
        numImages++;
        dialog.setValue(numImages);
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    }
}
```

It essentially loads images in a vector, and updates a newly constructed `QProgressDialog` with the progress.

This class inherits after `QUndoCommand` and `QObject`. It inherits after the first one, because it's used in `QUndoStack`. Object of B is also currently constructed in `A` class( which will be introduced shortly), and it is created on a heap, so we have a pointer to the object of B class inside A class.

And we have a second class, `A`, which inherits after `QWidget` directly. In my previous implementation, `A` was doing all that what `B`'s constructor does, in a separate method, not in the constructor. If I do everything the same way in A's `processImages` method, like:

```
void A::processImages(const QString &filepath) {
    QImageReader reader = QImageReader(filepath);
    int numImages = 0;

    QProgressDialog dialog("Loading images..", "Abort", 0, reader.imageCount());

    while (true) {
        QImage image = reader.read();
        if (image.isNull()) {
            break;
        }
        imagevec.push_back(image);
        numImages++;
        dialog.setValue(numImages);
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    }
}
```

It is getting drawn correctly while processing those images.

Everything here is done on 1 thread, no other threads are being created.

I know how it should usually be done, is to handle all of that in a separate thread and update main thread's GUI from the separate thread, and I will probably remake it to do that, but before that I want to know - why one thing works, and the second one not, when it seemingly does the same thing and is done in a similar way? The only difference is - the events are flushed for `B` in the constructor, and the whole class' object is being constructed on a heap, in `A` class, whereas in `A`'s case, the loop is being done in a method. Is it because of that? Maybe it is something wrong with the inheritance between those two? Why in the B's constructor it's not getting drawn, even when we are flushing events, and in A it gets drawn?